# How to fix "ambiguous package name 'libglib2.0-0'" problem?

Tags: dpkg

Using Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit, whenever I try `apt-get [anything]` or `dpkg [anything]` I get this error:

```
dpkg: error: el fichero de registros de disparadores menciona un 
      nombre de paquete ilegal `libglib2.0-0' (en el fichero
      `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules'):
      ambiguous package name 'libglib2.0-0' with more than one installed instance
```

Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem, after simply running `apt-get upgrade`. Somehow got mixed packages: i386 and amd64 at the same time.

First, I edited `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File` and removed all lines having `:i386`, then ran:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This deleted `libglib*` and one other package (it was a replacement of `lib-glib` with another name).

After multiple `apt-get clean`, `apt-get check`, `apt-get upgrade` (I do not remember right actions now) I finnally got `dpkg -l` working, filtered all packages for the wrong architecture (I have 64-bit kubuntu, so all i386 are wrong for me):

```
dpkg -l | grep ":amd" | awk '{print "\""$2"\""}'
```

Modified the output to put it all that into a single line and ran:

```
sudo dpkg --purge <dpkg output in single line>
```

All i386 packages were gone and I could then proceed with my upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the package performing an apt-get search, use the `remove` command and then re-install the library again.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not working... after looking for the package, I tried to remove but the same error was given. In fact, every action I try to perform via `apt-get` finishes with the same error